# Can't get layout to work correctly with dynamic textviews in a nested linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-linearlayout

In an XML layout that is a RelativeLayout I have a nested LinearLayout. Within this LinearLayout I dynamically add a few TextViews and buttons. My problem is, I can't get the items to appear under each other like would naturally happen within a LinearLayout. Here is the basic setup:

```
LinearLayout mobLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mobButtons);
mobLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
```

I remove all previous junk inside the layout because I reuse it.

```
mobLayout.addView(mobName);
mobLayout.addView(mobTextHP);
mobLayout.addView(fightButton);
mobLayout.addView(goBackButton);
```

These should appear one on top of the other, but instead appear all side by side. When I tried adding LinearLayout.LayoutParams to the first one, it wiped everything after it, or pushed it off screen, I couldn't tell.

Lastly, here is the LinearLayout XML area where these items are added:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mobButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fightText">

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this option for your LinearLayout

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: That was it, didn't think I had to add an orientation to the nested layout!